# Method for decomposing an algebra into a direct sum of matrix algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, representation-theory

I'm reading a paper which says that there is a standard way to decompose a (finite dimensional) algebra into a direct sum of matrix algebras by finding elements of the algebra which satisfy:
$$e_{ij}e_{kl}=\delta_{jk}e_{il}$$

Question: What is the procedure/where can I read more about how this decomposition works?

In the specific application given the algebra is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ with a given basis.

Comment: Such elements $e_{ij}$ would correspond to standard basis elements of a matrix elements. Note this notation fails to illustrate the algebra is a *direct sum* of *distinct* matrix algebras. One could write $$ \large e_{ij}^{(k)}e_{i'j'}^{(k')}=\delta_{kk'}\delta_{ji'} e_{ij'}^{(k)} $$ where the upper subscript keeps track of which matrix algebra in the direct sum the element corresponds to. Anyway, some keywords are "orthogonal idempotents" and "Peirce decomposition."

Comment: Also your claim isn't true for general: not every finite-dimensional unital $\Bbb C$-algebra is equivalent to a direct sum of $M_n(\Bbb C)$s and $M_n(\Bbb H)$s. This is true for group algebras though, or semisimple algebras in general, which is the Artin-Wedderburn theorem.

Comment: @runway44 Given that relation, wont the elements of the algebra mapped to those matrices not always be orthogonal? It seems for Peirce decomposition they must all be orthogonal. For example $e_{12}e_{21} = e_{11}$

Comment: I am not saying the $e_{ij}$ are all orthogonal idempotents of the Peirce decomposition, they just span the summands that are obtained in the (two-sided) Peirce decomposition. The "diagonal" elements $e_{ii}$ are the orthogonal idempotents, and $e_{ii}Ae_{jj}=\Bbb Re_{ij}$ are the summands of the Peirce decomposition. BTW what is the source you're talking about?

Comment: The paper is [here](https://www.math.tamu.edu/~rowell/DRWv10.pdf), page 15 Definition 3.13 is what I'm trying to understand.

Comment: Okay. Does it make sense that having such elements $e_{ij}$ (or really $e_{ij}^{(k)}$) in the algebra allows us to decompose it as a direct sum of matrix algebras, and why someone would think to look for such elements?

Comment: I'm not sure it's totally clear to me yet. I see that that relation is the relation for standard basis elements for the matrix algebras, so it makes sense to find elements which identify with those. Do you then just take the set of orthogonal idempotents from those elements to use to build the decomposition making sure they sum to 1?

Comment: You just turn algebra elements $e_{ij}$ into matrices $e_{ij}$ and extend linearly. Every algebra element will be a sum of these $e_{ij}$, so this gives you a way to turn any algebra element into a matrix (at least when the algebra is equivalent to a single matrix algebra - when it's a direct sum of multiple matrix algebras, you need to keep track of which summand the matrix is supposed to be part of).

Comment: Is there a standard method for finding the elements $e_{ij}$? Also is your $\mathbb{R}$ above the real numbers?

Comment: In math $\Bbb R$ means reals, yes. I think your $\sum e_{ii}$ is missing an equals sign, but the sum of *all* of them (even between different matrix algebras) ought to be the multiplicative identity of the algebra. The sum of all the $e_{ii}$s corresponding to a particular matrix algebra ought to correspond to that matrix algebra's identity matrix. To find the $e_{ij}$s you generally find $e_{ii}$s first and get the $e_{ij}$s from them. Arguably more often you get matrices by having the algebra act on representations aka modules first, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: Since in this case the algebra is over $\mathbb{C}$ wouldn't it be $e_{ii}Ae_{jj} = \mathbb{C} e_{ij}$?

Comment: Ah, true. ${}{}$

Comment: Thank you for answering all these questions